# PHP-Login script isn't working

Tags: php

The `PHP` script supposed to receive two variables : username and password but it doesn't do that and it always "echo" : "missing input".
I tried to echo the two variables but nothing was echoed, which i think means that they are not initialized.

This is the script:

```
require_once ('connect.php');
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
        $query = "Select * from merchant where username='$username' and password = '$password' ";
        $r = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
            echo "Welcome";

            mysqli_close($con);
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong password or username";
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "you must type both inputs";
    }
}
else {
    echo "missing input";
}
```

I tried sending the post data using Postman and via HTML page but both returned the same thing: "missing input"

This is the HTML i used

```
<form action="mlog.php" method="post">
 <input type="textbox" name="username" value="username" />
  <input type="textbox" name="password" value="password" />
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: And the HTML that is sending the data is what?

Comment: do print_r($_POST) before if and see what it prints?
or share complete code with HTML.

Comment: pls post HTML code

Comment: need HTML code to anwser

Comment: Please also post the html form

Comment: Don't store your passwords in plain-text! This is not secure *at all!* PHP has built-in functions which you should use to handle storing of passwords, see the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function 
which is a lot more secure!

Comment: i'm sending the post data using `POSTMAN

Comment: @Qirel its just for testing, later on i'm gonna use that function

Comment: @nadreen "just for testing" is **no excuse** to write fundamentally insecure code! also: your code is wide open for **SQL Injection** - use parameterized statements to protect yourself, and do it **now**. and change your way of thinking - the mindest of "i'll deal with security later" is the reason for almost all security issues.

Comment: We've seen it time and time again, "*I'll deal with security later*" - I understand you want your code to work, but security is never something you push off - implement proper hashing of passwords, and usage of prepared statements **right away**. ;-) You'll save yourself doing the work twice, too.

Comment: `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1); //display those errors
require_once ('connect.php');
if(!empty(trim($_POST['username'])) && !empty(trim($_POST['password']))){ $username= $_POST['username'];$password= $_POST['password'];$query = "Select * from merchant where username='$username' and password = '$password' ";$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){echo "Welcome";mysqli_close($con);}else{echo "Wrong password or username";mysqli_close($con);}}else{echo "missing input";}`

Comment: @nadreen Have you tested the HTML you just added to your question. Do you still get the same result?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes i try and do that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its `<input type="text">`

```
<form action="mlog.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="username" value="username" />
  <input type="text" name="password" value="password" />
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: According to another comment I had on my anwer (wich is now deleted), it doesn't make any sense because the browser will send it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the login button was clicked, then check if the username and password are not empty then assign the vars to them if not.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];
        $query = "Select * from merchant where username='$username' and password = '$password' ";
        $r = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if($r) {
            echo "Welcome";
            //redirect

        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong password or username";
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "you must type both inputs";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: good coding:-  `$r = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)) {`  are you serious?

Comment: that was silly.. you are right, only looked at the problem he was facing with the inputs being empty.  @Anant